# Rails 4 how to speed up json rendering

Tags: json, performance, ruby-on-rails-4, rendering, jbuilder

I have 1500 small objects to render for a webservice inside a rails 4 application. I use json as format with jbuilder for templates. I already changed the json engine to oj in the app initializer:

```
 require 'oj_mimic_json'
#MultiJson.use :yajl

Oj.mimic_JSON

# jbuilder json templates
Jbuilder.key_format camelize: :lower
```

a single rendered json object looks like this:

```
center: {lat: 45.962153536249, lon: 7.68207088549831}
lat: 45.962153536249
lon: 7.68207088549831
n: "Zermatt-Cervinia"
st: 80
sy: 0


Rendered json_partials/_snow_in_resort.json.jbuilder (0.5ms)
Rendered json_partials/_snow_in_resort.json.jbuilder (0.5ms)
....
Rendered resorts/find.json.jbuilder (4213.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 4351ms (Views: 3924.3ms | ActiveRecord: 306.8ms | Solr: 0.0ms)
```

But still I need 150 ms for 101 kb on my localhost which is way too slow for the task I want to accomplish on the UI.
What do I have to do to speed up here? Which things should I check?
I appreciate help.
Best,
Philip

**update**

I optimized my active record queries down to ActiveRecord: 77.8ms , nevertheless the view rendering is still too slow

Comment: Is there maybe any way to use threats to do the rendering in parallel?

Comment: Provide sample object in a json format. Do you only mean rendering or rendering + SQL query to obtain objects?

Comment: In other words, is your response always the same , changes over time, or is completely dynamic based on request?

Comment: it s dynamic based on the request.

Answer (score 6):

You can explore using HTTP Caching using Varnish. Here's a great article describing different caching techniques (Fragment Caching, HTTP Caching, etc. ) in Rails 4. It has good explanation on caching JSON responses.

**Rails 4 and Caching**

http://www.slatestudio.com/blog/p/caching-in-rails-4-applications

**Here's another on Rails and Varnish**

http://www.hward.com/scale-rails-with-varnish-http-caching-layer/

[lacquer](https://github.com/russ/lacquer) a popular gem with drop-in support for varnish caching in rails

**If you want to get into little more detail on what is HTTP caching, Here's a really good writeup**

https://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/

**Ryan Bates has a excellent tutorial on Rails Cast but it's a Pro Episode**

http://railscasts.com/episodes/321-http-caching

```
UPDATE
```

**Geocoder Gem**

Based on some comments below, I would suggest looking into using the [Geocoder](http://www.rubygeocoder.com/) gem. It's been around for a while and is very well optimized for Points of Interest search, like what you are trying to do. It also does lot more than that.

**Spatial Index**
If you have already tried it, and are not satisfied, can you please post some details on what kind of optimizations you are using on your database to speed up the query? You can significantly speed up POI queries by using spatial indexes on the table?

Here's a good article on spatial indexes:

http://daniel-azuma.com/articles/georails/part-6

> Some performance testing ideas

You might be able to test if it is indeed the rendering that is slowing you down by coming up with a good test case. Try querying for things towards top, middle and bottom of your points table. Also for different number of response objects in your JSON, and different number of properties in your JSON object. 
Right now I see, that lat, lon is redundant.  Try removing them and compare times for huge number of results, if it is indeed the rendering that is slowing you down, fewer the properties, faster responses you should see.

Also, if your properties, (name, st, sy etc.. ) are coming from relationships instead of same table as points, try de-normalizing your DB to see if you get faster view rendering..

Comment: It's not a caching issue, since the response is always different, based on the request.

Comment: can you please provide some details on what kind of request it is? is it some kind of Geocoding or Points of interest search? In which case you might have to explore better geo-indxing options in your database. Also, dynamic request's too benefit from HTTP caching... but to address your case specifically , more details on what kind of request, query, response will be helpful.

Comment: I am searching for snow_resorts based on there geo coordinate. But I already improved the query to ActiveRecord: 77.8ms . So it's not a querying problem, I think.

Comment: I see, so it is a Points of interest search. Have you tried the Geocoder Gem? I have used it several times before on fairly huge database, and have been very satisfied with performance.. http://www.rubygeocoder.com/

Comment: Yea, it s really cool. But it's not exactly fitting my needs. I started doing my own calculations in postgis which was very fast. But the biggest boost was switching to sunpot's build in postgis search which is blazing fast. That's why I am sure in this case it is a rendering issue

Comment: probably pointless question, but.. you are not developing on windows are you?

Comment: Hehe.No on osx now, or on ubuntu sometimes. But never again on windows.

Comment: cool.. Optimizations is always tricky.. take a look at this very old question of mine, on similar task as yours, but on millions of high,density LIDAR point clouds. It was about, query optimization, and I never got a better answer, but you might get something useful out of it. I have shown how I usd spatial indexes.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6654875/optimize-nearest-neighbor-query-on-70-million-extremely-high-density-spatial-poi

Comment: I am not sure whether there is much more potential on the gis side, since I am already using bounding boxes to narrow down potential result sets, and then there is solr which is returning the required results in a ridiculous fast way. So I a stuck since I don't have a clue to tackle the rendering faster.

Comment: just curious.. its been a while, did you ever get this figured out?

Comment: Yes, it turned out some deeply nested property in the json structure was hitting the db each time.